# How to deal with dates in Linq Query?

Tags: c#, linq, date

I'm getting a `NotSupportedException`:

**Method 'System.TimeSpan FromMinutes(Double)' has no supported translation to SQL.**

When running this query:

```
var searchSchedules =
    from searchSchedule in db.SearchSchedules
    where searchSchedule.Active.Value &&
          searchSchedule.LastChecked.Value <
            DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(
              searchSchedule.CheckFrequencyMinutes)) &&
          searchSchedule.PublishingConfigurationId == pubConfig.Id
          select searchSchedule;
```

Obviously the problem is with the `TimeSpan` part of the query. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just trying to check whether a specified number of minutes has passed since the last check you can rewrite like this:

```
var searchSchedules =
    from searchSchedule in db.SearchSchedules
    where searchSchedule.Active.Value &&
            ((DateTime.UtcNow - searchSchedule.LastChecked.Value).Minutes >= searchSchedule.CheckFrequencyMinutes) &&
          searchSchedule.PublishingConfigurationId == pubConfig.Id
          select searchSchedule;
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using your solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to break this query up into two pieces. One piece executes against the database and the second piece executes on the client, as follows:

```
// This executes against the database
var query1 = from searchSchedule in db.SearchSchedules
             where searchSchedule.Active.Value
             && searchSchedule.PublishingConfigurationId == pubConfig.Id
             select searchSchedule;

// This executes on the client
var query2 = from query1 as IEnumerable()
             where query1.LastChecked.Value < DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(query1.CheckFrequencyMinutes))
```

I often do queries like this, when I want to include a function in a query that SQL Server wouldn't know how to handle. In the second query, converting query1 to IEnumerable will force it to execute on the client, against the .NET framework, instead of your database.

You will need to determine how many rows might need to be processed on the client to determine how efficient this might be.

Comment: This approach will result in a very inefficient scenario when dealing with large datasets as where a database can simply use a very fast indexed column, the client will iterate through the entire IEnumerable returned.

Comment: I use this approach as well, yet often worry about the unforeseen volume of data that may be brought back to the client only to be tossed out by the where clause.

Comment: That is certainly a possibility. I just showed this as an alternative. There are already two filters on the first query. You will need to determine how many rows might need to be processed on the client.

Comment: If this was written in Sql rather than Linq would you still take the same approach?  I'm a big advocate of Linq however one massive downside I have noticed is the ease of mixing server and client processing causing inefficiencies that simply would not arise if writing a stored procedure